# React native meteor vs react native and rest api

Tags: reactjs, meteor, react-native, graphql, vulcan

I am architecting for new application and finalized to use react for web and react native for mobile and graphQl. Now I am wondering whether to build a server using node and express or to use Vulcanjs and build web application using meteor, react and graphQl? My main concern is about mobile application, if meteor goes well with react native? Is it better to do server side rendering for mobile application?

Answer (score 1):

[`react-native-meteor`](https://github.com/inProgress-team/react-native-meteor) works fine with React Native app with Meteor backend.  There is no need of server side rendering for Mobile Application with React Native.

If you are using Meteor and React as web application you can reuse the logic of most of the components in React Native application. [`react-native-meteor`](https://github.com/inProgress-team/react-native-meteor) will ensure the reactivity of mobile application and this package won't require any REST APIs to work with Meteor backend.